# Gd library vs Html canvas element

Tags: html5-canvas, gd

I'm new in web development and I've used both of them and apply basically the same functionalities, which tool is more effective (more used, under more active development) and has more interesting features HTML Canvas element or PHP GD library?

Comment: Canvas is an image container not an API or library, You may be thinking of the CanvasRenderingContext2D API there is also WebGL. It comes down to do you want to render client side or server side.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you're building. For example, HTML Canvas can render via WebGL any 3d, whereas GD library is a 2D drawing library (even though you can fake 3D there.)

Another point is, one is backend (PHP,) the other is frontend (HTML) meaning in one, the processing is taken by your server, vs taken by the user, on the user device, which sometimes can be very slow.

I would say, given my experience and recent developments, the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) offers more options than PHP GD. And if you want to do it in the backend, you can use [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas).

Additionally, because Canvas happens in the front-end, there's an option for it to be interactive (whether 2d or 3d) which any back-end rendering framework would not offer.

```
|-------------------------------------|
| Feature     | GD      | HTML Canvas |
|-------------------------------------|
| 3D          | No      | Yes         |
| Static      | Yes     | Yes         |
| Interactive | No      | Yes         |
| Performance | Server  | User        |
|-------------------------------------|
```

**TL;DR: if you have to do too many calculations, go back-end, if you have to do just a few, but many times (different for each user) do it front-end.**